# Rails: How to get a model to "inherit" attributes from a parent model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, model, parent-child

I have a model "Thing" and a model "Category", which have_many of each other through another model "ThingCategories". I want each Category to have a certain set of attributes, and when a Thing is created belonging to that Category, I want the Thing to gain those attributes. For example, if there's a Category called "film" with the attribute :director, and one called "book" with the attribute :author, and I create a Thing called "Harry Potter" which belongs to both categories, then Harry Potter should have both a :director and :author attribute. All I want is both attributes listed on the completed things/show view.

So far I've created an "Attribute" model and two connecting models "ThingAttribute" and "CategoryAttribute", but I'm not sure where to go from here. Am I on the right track?

I'm using rails 4.0.10.

Comment: You could add a simple check to your model, if @attribute.ThingAttribute.present? ... Then display the author. Similarly, if @attribute.CategoryAttribute.present? ... Then display the film title.

Comment: As you've started.. import during the initilise method.

Answer (score -1):

How I'd do this..

I'd create the attributes as parts of a module.  So I have a book_helper.rb and movie_helper.rb

I'd then import the correct file during the initialise function.  It would be object specific.. 
When doing this I'd consider name-spacing the methods so you don't get a clash.

I'm not sure if this is the right way, but it would be how I'd go about it (unless someone told me a better way)